# Nested views in Ionic ui-router not working

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm using Ionic, simple routing is working but nested not working .
**here's my config :**

```
.state('category', {
    url: '/category',
    //If in a folder, template/welcome.html
    templateUrl: 'views/category/category.html',
    controller: 'categoryController'
})
.state('category.sport', {
    url: '/sport',
    views: {
        'sportContent' :{
            templateUrl: 'views/category/sport/sport.html'
            // controller: 'sportController'
        }
    }

})
```

and here's my **html** :

```
<button class="button btn-custom button-full button-assertive icon icon-left ion-android-bicycle no-border red-custom no-margin">

       <a href="#/category/sport"></a>
</button>
```

Am i missing Something ? Thanks in advance

Comment: how your `category.html` looks?

Comment: <ion-pane>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-header bar-light">
        <h1 class="title">
            دسته بندی

        </h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>

<button class="button btn-custom button-full button-assertive icon icon-left ion-android-bicycle no-border red-custom no-margin">

       <a href="#/category/sport"></a>
</button>  
</ion-pane>

Comment: you need to add abstrat:true in your routing to route to your child classes